# How to code for optional command line parameters in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

My program has to accept optional command line parameters where there will be either 1 or 3 parameters (executable, number of rows, number of columns). If argc is anything other than 3, we have to create a board that is 10x10 (I've already made a function to create the board).

I'm not sure how to account for this. One restriction on main.c is that we're only allowed to declare/assign variables and call functions, so I'm stuck on how I'm supposed to make this work. My initial idea was to write a function correctNumOfArgs to check if argc is 3, and then return true or false. I would then use that result in a different function to determine how to create the board, but that would still require me to pass argv[1] and argv[2] as parameters in the function and they might not even exist. How do I get around this? Note: I looked at other questions regarding optional command line parameters and they suggested solutions more advanced than what we have learned. Is there a more basic solution to this?

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: You seem to already know *how* to do this - use `argc` to check for the number of arguments. We don't know what kind of "restrictions" you have on actually writing code, is this for a school assignment or something?

Comment: writing a function just to check `argc` seems a bit overkill to me .. just check `argc` in `main` ... `if (argc==1){ create_board(10, 10); } else if (argc==3) { create_board(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]); }else{ printError} ... return 0;`

Comment: Although perhaps it evades the spirit of the problem, it seems that all you need to do is have `main()` call a `main_real()` function that is not subject to the same limitations, passing `argc` and `argv` to it.

Comment: But perhaps what you're looking for is more like `int num_rows = (argc < 3) ? 10 : atoi(argv[1])`.

Comment: @yano Yes, that is the obvious solution. However a restriction on this assignment is that we are only allowed to call functions and declare/assign variables in main

Comment: ok? My very limited pseudo code follows those restrictions. Declare the board in `main`, pass it to the `create_board` function which will dynamically allocate it... then after that call the next function in `main` that uses the board.

Comment: @GregHewgill yes, this is for an assignment. I understand that I can check argc for the number of arguments; where I'm stuck is how to assign argv[1] to be numRows and argv[2] to be numCols in a separate function that is called in main

Comment: I think you need to go get some clarification from your teacher (or maybe just add some clarification for me if I'm the only one). Passing `argv` to a function doesn't violate your "_in main we are only allowed to call functions and/or declare/assign variables_" restriction. That's not even a restriction. Every `main` in the history of `c` has done that except for HelloWorld and similar. I declare/assign variables and call functions from `main` all the time.

Comment: @yano I'm sorry for not wording it better. My problem was that I was trying to split argv before passing it as parameters, when I should've just passed the whole thing and accessed different elements within the function, as seen in the answers below. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass both `argc` and `argv` to a function and have it return rows and cols.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rows = 10, cols = 10;
    check_args(argc, argv, &rows, &cols);
    return 0;
}

void check_args(int argc, char **argv, int *rows, int *cols) {
    if (argc == 3) {
        *rows = atoi(argv[1]);
        *cols = atoi(argv[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the arguments don't exist for a code path you don't take.

What I mean:

```
if(3==argc)
make_board(argv[1], argv[2]);
else if(1==argc)
make_board("10", "10");
else
{
/*error*/
}
```

If numArgs is not 3 then that path is not taken so the non-existent arguments aren't used and are never evaluated.

Comment: Yes but in main we are only allowed to call functions or declare/assign variables. Thus I would need to pass argv[1] and argv[2] as parameters in a function which wouldn't work.

Comment: So pass `argc` and `argv` and in the function, determine the rows / cols based on `argc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easily with variable assignment using a *ternary* operator to check if `argc > 2` and if it is, convert the supplied arguments to `rows` and `cols`, otherwise, use the default `10` for each, e.g.

```
errno = 0;

int rows = argc > 2 ? (int)strtol (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 10,
    cols = argc > 2 ? (int)strtol (argv[2], NULL, 10) : 10;

if (errno) { /* handle error in strtol conversion    */
             /* (you should also check for overflow) */ }
```

(**note:** always check for error in the conversion before continuing -- you can move this to a function and fully validate the `strtol` conversion by checking `nptr` against `endptr` to insure characters were converted, and then saving the value to a temporary `long` value, you can insure the values are between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` (and reasonable) before assigning to `rows`, `cols`)

If you must use a function, just pass a pointer to `rows` and `cols` as parameters and then set the values stored at each respective address within the function. That way you have a simple function call that can return `0/1` for success/failure and update the values for `rows, cols` through the pointers passed as parameters.